# MMS pictures not opening

Tags: photos, samsung-galaxy-s-4, mms

I have a Galaxy S4 on Verizon - rooted, but still running the stock ROM. Recently I noticed that I am unable to open MMS messages on my phone. I receive them, and am able to view the thumbnail, but when tapping on it to open it in the gallery app, the Gallery app will open, and then freeze on a black screen (never displaying the picture). Sometimes, after a minute, it will crash. I tried another gallery app (QuickPic), and it will open and then close right after.